# What does the following assignment do?

Tags: java

I've found this BinaryTree class implementation in the Java Structures book, but I don't completely understand what the last assignment of the constructor does (three assignments in one statement).

```
protected E val; // value associated with node
protected BinaryTree<E> parent; // parent of node
protected BinaryTree<E> left, right; // children of node
public BinaryTree()
    // post: constructor that generates an empty node
    {
        val = null;
        parent = null; 
        left = right = this;
}
```

Comment: You can look at it as `left = (right = this)`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this assignment as two actual assignments:

```
right = this;
left = right;
```

Because assignments will be evaluated from right to left so for better understanding `left = right = this` is equal to `left = (right = this)`. So the result of `right = this` assignment will be basically reference which `right` points to and then you just assign it to `left` field.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Grzegorz said it's a shortcut to assign the instance object to variable left and right.

```
left = this;
right = this;
```

so every instance of BinaryTree you create, that instance object is assigned to variable left and right.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shortcut syntax of doing *two* assignments in one go.

It's practically equivalent to:

```
right = this;
left = this;
```

Comment: @KorayTugay the distinction is probably important only in a multi-threaded code, right? Way above the level of interest of OP.